# ¿Cómo intercalar entre numeros absolutos y relativos en Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Tengo las siguientes líneas en mi vimrc las cuales funcionan a la perfección en Linux, pero no funcionan en OS X ni Windows.

```
set relativenumber
nmap <F5> :set relativenumber! number!<CR>
imap <F5> <ESC>:set relativenumber! number!<CR>
```

La idea es que al presionar F5 cambie entre relativos y absolutos, pero el cambio sólo funciona la primera vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo resuelto mediante una función que verifica en primer lugar el estado para determinar que camino seguir:

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set number
    set norelativenumber
  else
    set number  
    set relativenumber
  endif

endfunc

noremap <F5> :call NumberToggle()<cr>
inoremap <F5> <c-o>:call NumberToggle()<cr>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esto me funcionó muy bien en OSX y Windows, pero no en Linux.

Comment: Me alegro, raro lo de Linux, justamente lo copié de mi .vim de un Linux Mint. Algún problema de CR/LF? Saludos.